# Ranking values to determine highest value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, partitioning

I have data that looks as such:

```
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| ID  | score1 | score2 | score3 |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| 123 |     14 |    561 |    580 |
| 123 |    626 |    771 |    843 |
| 123 |    844 |    147 |    904 |
| 456 |    922 |    677 |    301 |
| 456 |    665 |    578 |    678 |
| 456 |    416 |    631 |    320 |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
```

What I'm trying to do is create another column that provides which score is the highest amongst the three. Remember, I'm not looking for what the value is, I'm looking for the name of the column. Therefore, the final output would look as such:

```
+-----+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| ID  | score1 | score2 | score3 | high_score |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| 123 |     14 |    561 |    580 | score3     |
| 123 |    626 |    771 |    843 | score3     |
| 123 |    844 |    998 |    904 | score2     |
| 456 |    922 |    677 |    301 | score1     |
| 456 |    665 |    578 |    678 | score3     |
| 456 |    416 |    631 |    320 | score1     |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+------------+
```

I keep trying to do a query involving `RANK()` involving `PARTITION BY` but it's not giving me what I'm looking for and I'm officially stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redshift, this might be most easily done using `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case greatest(score1, score2, score3)
             when score1 then 'score1'
             when score2 then 'score2'
             when score3 then 'score3'
        end) as high_score_name,
       greatest(score1, score2, score3) as high_score
from t;
```

Comment: Gordon - Worked like a charm! Thank you. Another quick question: What would I do if I wanted to do the 2nd highest?

Comment: That is more complicated.  You should ask a new question, provide sample data and explain what to do in the event of ties.