# Finding the second greatest value out of a set of columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[I had an original question relating to how to find the greatest value and it was helpfully solved.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734297/ranking-values-to-determine-highest-value/58734540?noredirect=1#comment103763204_58734540) That was done using this query:

```
select t.*,
       (case greatest(score1, score2, score3)
             when score1 then 'score1'
             when score2 then 'score2'
             when score3 then 'score3'
        end) as high_score_name,
       greatest(score1, score2, score3) as high_score
from t;
```

This works like a charm and creates the desired output, which looks as such:

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
|  ID  |  score1  |  score2  |  score3  |  high_score  |
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
|  123 |       14 |      561 |      580 |  score3      |
|  456 |      626 |      771 |      843 |  score3      |
|  789 |      844 |      998 |      904 |  score2      |
|  111 |      922 |      677 |      301 |  score1      |
|  222 |      665 |      578 |      678 |  score3      |
|  333 |      416 |      631 |      320 | score2       |
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

But now I'm trying to find the second greates value so that the output generated looks like such:

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+
|  ID  |  score1  |  score2  |  score3  |  high_score  | second_score |
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+
|  123 |       14 |      561 |      580 |  score3      | score2       |
|  456 |      626 |      771 |      843 |  score3      | score2       |
|  789 |      844 |      998 |      904 |  score2      | score3       |
|  111 |      922 |      677 |      301 |  score1      | score2       |
|  222 |      665 |      578 |      678 |  score3      | score1       |
|  333 |      416 |      631 |      320 | score2       | score1       |
+------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

The original individual who answered the question suggested putting together a new question. I should probably consider ties, but the figures we have go enough decimal places to break any.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no ties, you can use another `case` expression:

```
select (case when score1 not in (least(score1, score2, score3), greatest(score1, score2, score3))
             then 'score1'
             when score1 not in (least(score1, score2, score3), greatest(score1, score2, score3))
             then 'score2'
             when score1 not in (least(score1, score2, score3), greatest(score1, score2, score3))
             then 'score3'
        end) as second_score
```

This does *not* generalize well to more columns.

If this is something you need, I would recommend changing your data model so you have the data in *rows* not *columns*:

```
id    score    score_number
123      14         1
123     561         2
123     580         3
. . .
```

Your questions would then be much simpler to answer.

Comment: Is there a good way to do what you recommend? Like cascade the results downward in rows rather than across columns?

Comment: @gooponyagrinch . . . It requires reloading the table or a query to unpivot the data (in Redshift, probably a `union all` query).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option to do it is to unpivot the table (have one row per score) and then rank them. If you want to have exact output with original scores you can either pivot table again, or join the results by `id`.

That's my proposal:

```sql
with input(id, score1, score2, score3) as (
    select 123, 14, 561,  580 union all
    select 456, 626, 771, 843 union all
    select 789, 844, 998, 904 union all
    select 111, 922, 677, 301 union all
    select 222, 665, 578, 678 union all
    select 333, 416, 631, 320
),
     unpivotted(id, score_label, score) as (
         select
             id,
             case x
                 when 1 then 'score1'
                 when 2 then 'score2'
                 when 3 then 'score3'
                 end,
             case x
                 when 1 then score1
                 when 2 then score2
                 when 3 then score3
                 end
         from input
                  cross join (select 1 as x union all select 2 union all select 3) as three
     ),
     ranked as (
         select *,
                rank() over (partition by id order by score desc) as rnk
         from unpivotted
     )
select distinct
    id,
    nth_value(score_label, 1) over (partition by id order by rnk rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) as high_score_label,
    nth_value(score_label, 2) over (partition by id order by rnk rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as second_score_label,
    nth_value(score, 1) over (partition by id order by rnk rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) as high_score,
    nth_value(score, 2) over (partition by id order by rnk rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as second_score
from ranked
order by id
```

Result:

```
#   id  high_score_label    second_score_label  high_score  second_score
1   111 score1              score2              922         677
2   123 score3              score2              580         561
3   222 score3              score1              678         665
4   333 score2              score1              631         416
5   456 score3              score2              843         771
6   789 score2              score3              998         904
```